# What's the reasoning behind China's Go Out policy, did they publish a white paper or made any public statement explaining the reasoning behind it?

Tags: china, economy, international, foreign-direct-investment

> Most nations favour attracting inward foreign investment, and support
> outward foreign investment only passively.[citation needed] The
> People's Republic of China, however, attaches importance to both
> inward and outward foreign investment.[citation needed]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Out_policy

Can you provide information on the reasons behind China's unique approach to foreign investment, where it places significance on both attracting inward foreign investment and actively supporting outward foreign investment, in contrast to the more common international practice of favoring inward investment?What's the reasoning behind China's Go Out policy, did they publish a white paper or made any public statement explaining the reasoning behind it?

Most countries favor attracting inward foreign investment and support outward foreign investment only passively, and yet China decided to put as much importance on both. Did China publish a white paper explaining the reasoning behind their policy? They often publish a white paper explaining the reasoning behind their decisions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you've got DVs on this, but much of the reasons (and sources for them) are given in the Wikipedia article you link. I did find one that has somewhat more of an actual quote than what's in Wikipedia.

Comment: The first quoted paragraph is highly dubious (and indeed does not seem any longer to be on the current version of Wikipedia page). // *China's unique approach* This is false. There is nothing "unique" about China's approach. The [Government of Singapore](https://www.enterprisesg.gov.sg/grow-your-business/go-global) for example actively encourages and assists local companies in expanding and investing globally. Many other countries also do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/tr/pdf/ADA570470.pdf

> In the mid-1990s, the going out strategy known in Mandarin
> as zou chu qu was inaugurated by the State Economic and Trade Commission by selecting 120
> “national champions” to go abroad as the spearhead of Chinese foreign business engagement.
> In 1997, the 15th Congress of the Chinese Communist Party (CCP) encouraged State Owned
> Enterprises (SOEs) to enter the competitive world market by investing abroad. **The then-President
> Jiang Zemin communicated the government’s intent to “establish highly competitive large
> enterprise groups with trans-regional, inter-trade, cross ownership and transnational operations”
> in order to “encourage Chinese investors to invest abroad in areas that can bring China’s
> competitive advantage into play so as to make better use of both Chinese and foreign markets and
> resources.”**
> In a related move, Jiang advised SOEs to go overseas in search of natural resources.
> This push from the top resulted in Chinese trade with the resource abundant regions of Southeast
> Asia, Latin America, and Africa growing by an amazing 600 percent during the period 2001-2007.

The direct quote is cited [therein] from

> Jiang Zemin, report delivered at the 15th National Congress of the Communist Party of China on September 12, 1997.

TBH "going out" to find raw resources is [not exactly](https://academic.oup.com/book/853/chapter-abstract/135460119?redirectedFrom=fulltext) a new strategy, despite what Wikipedia says. Yeah, there's the more subtle issue of how that's done.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the underlying reason is that China has net positive foreign trade. Every year they have spare cash lying around, if they try to invest it all in domestic economy that would likely cause realty and stock bubbles, on top of what they already have.

So it makes sense for them to invest these money abroad. Especially as they are denominated in USD/EUR. As Russian example has shown, holding USD directly is dangerous as these assets may be frozen, with US/EU not honoring their IOUs. But if you have these assets invested in a range of countries, that will provide a steady annual income and these obligations are much harder to freeze by third parties.

This approach is not without its own problems, such as bad debt to third world countries, but it also grows Chinese political outreach, which I guess they are happy about.

Comment: I think this is somewhat speculative. If anything, China [has started](https://www.cadtm.org/Part-2-Questions-Answers-on-China-as-a-Major-Creditor-Power#in_what_currencies_are_chinese_loans_granted) to loan more in its own currency in recent times (around 50% compared to under 20% last decade), and that happens since relations with the US in particular have soured. Many of these loans are said to also come with conditions that limit parts and sometimes labor to Chinese companies. So that's like China [indirectly] loaning to Chinese companies.

Comment: Thus the corect de-risking there is to give loans [e.g. to Africa] in yuans. It's true though that many Chinese millionaires/billionaires do seek to park their money abroad in real estate etc., often in Western countries. That might not be officially encouraged though.

Comment: Some Chinese loans [are](https://time.com/6266658/china-emerges-major-global-lender/) intended though to substitute IMF ones, and facilitate repayment of older loans by other countries, e.g. the large loans China gave to Argentina are probably like that. For those purposes, it makes sense for China to still lend in foreign currencies, assuming the original loans were denominated like that (and Argentina's almost certainly were). However, this is a relatively new policy that didn't exist or motivate the initial wave of "going out", decades ago.

Comment: And it's also more risky, considering e.g. that the guy who won the Argentine presidential elections more recently isn't exactly a fan of China. https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/china-congratulates-argentine-vote-winner-despite-assassin-jab-1.2000948

Comment: You are sure that an account is vulnerable to freezing based on the currency it is denominated in, not the country the bank is based in?

Comment: @JoelHarmon: well, it's vulnerable to both, assuming it's not disbursed in just one installment. Once it's only in the repayment period, the risks are supported only by the creditor, of course, unless there was collateral, another guarantor etc. Which Chinese credits do sometimes have though, incl. collateral consisting of raw resources.

Comment: @JoelHarmon: in [one dataset](https://research.hktdc.com/en/article/Njk1Nzc1NTQz), about 25% of the Chinese loans were collateralized with commondites (i.e. raw resources) but that amounted to only about 12% of the combined loans figure. For the poorest countries, China seems to do this more often, e.g. it was 75% for Angola.

Comment: Great catch, but the policy originated in 2000. It was quite inconvenient to loan in Yuan back then, since thr Chinese econony was tiny and Yuan was an exotic asset back then. So it wasn't a big motivation back then.